# Highcharts (javascript) strange artifact (bug?) with simple graphic

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have this very simple code (data provided) in Javascript running Highcharts in order to create a simple graphic with simple configuration. Any ideas on why the last part of the graphic is being painted incorrectly?

Here is the jsfiddle link so you can see what I'm talking about (x axis at 5pm).
http://goo.gl/J5oWuE

The image with the strange graphic generated:
[image: http://imgur.com/kF62qWp]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your series is not sorted by time. You have the following:

```
...
[Date.UTC(2014, 02, 7, 13, 14), 1351],
[Date.UTC(2014, 02, 7, 14, 03), 6391],
[Date.UTC(2014, 02, 7, 20, 02), 5231],
[Date.UTC(2014, 02, 7, 16, 28), 837],
[Date.UTC(2014, 02, 7, 17, 00), 541],
...
```

Sort all your data with ascending time scale.

Comment: true! I was looking for some kind of details like that but couldn't find it. Thanks a lot for saving me more spent hours :)